# How to sumuniqueifs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| ORDER ID | STATUS | MONTH OF TRX DATE | PREMIUM | AGENT NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000-8359 | PAID | December | 5000 | JOHN DOE |
| 1000-8360 | PAID | December | 6000 | JOHN DOE |
| 1000-8360 | PAID | December | 6000 | JOHN DOE |

So this is how my table looks like. For some reason ORDER ID in my table showed multiple times. And I can't do sumifs because it would double sum for the same ORDER ID. Sumuniqueifs with the same logic as Countuniqueifs would help to sort it but the formula isn't exist in google sheets.

I want to sum the premium of John Doe in December. If I use

```
=sumifs(D:D, B:B, "PAID", C:C, "December",E:E, "JOHN DOE")
```

the results would be 17,000 (6,000 + 6,000 + 5,000).

But what I really want is for the result to show 11,000 (6,000 + 5,000). Because this ORDER ID -> 1000-8360 (row 2 and 3) showed twice in the table. It's the same order and I don't want to double sum.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169899/sumif-for-unique-entries

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,unique(A:E),
    sum(ifna(filter(index(Σ,,4),index(Σ,,2)="PAID",index(Σ,,3)="December",index(Σ,,5)="JOHN DOE"))))
```

[image]